# CSS issue inside table trying to get div increasing height of td

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get dynamic height with below paragraph.

```
 <td>
    <b>audio systems</b> <br>
    <div style="position:absolute">
       <p>Do you need services of a company that specialises in audio systems? With expertise in all areas of audio systems, AAVI is the best choice.</p>
    </div>
 </td>
```

I cannot get this `td` to dynamically increase height for paragraph inside `div` tag. Instead it always goes over the `td` section even though I set width for the `div` and `p`. I don't want to have the `p` going over `div` or `td` section.

Is there a way we can get this working?

Comment: you could try giving the td a position:relative but without looking at the rest of your css, it's hard to say. What you can do if you're using chrome or firebug, is right-click the paragraph and select "inspect element", you can manually fiddle with the css and see the results. you can tick or untick style rules to see what the effect is.

Comment: Given this limited subset of HTML, it looks like you're trying to use tables for layout instead of semantics, in which case you shouldn't be using a table at all. Further, please include your CSS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <b>audio systems</b> <br>
    <div style="position:absolute">
   <p>Do you need services of a company that specialises in audio systems? With expertise in all areas of audio systems, AAVI is the best choice.</p>
    </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Only by removing `position:absolute;` or using JavaScript.

Making the `<div>` absolutely positioned [removes it from the normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning).